# What am I doing wrong with Java generics in this interface and method?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

**EDIT:** There is another wrinkle in here that I missed that turns out to make a big difference.  The method signature of `doAnotherThing` is instead the following:

```
<T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(List<Foo<T>> foo) {
    return foo.get(0).doSomething();
}
```

**Disregard the fact that it is a `List`, just pay attention to the fact that `List` is a generic class/interface.  I'm calling the method like so:**

```
doAnotherThing(new ArrayList<FooImpl>);
```

So, I have a class and interface defined like so:

```
abstract class Bar {
    // some neat stuff
}

class BarImpl extends Bar {
    // some cool stuff
}

interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T doSomething();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl> {
    BarImpl doSomething() {
        // Does something awesome
    }
}
```

This is all fine and dandy and works great.

Now, I have a method like so:

```
<T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(List<Foo<T>> foo) {
    return foo.get(0).doSomething();
}
```

**This method is a generic method in a completely different class and is not part of the chain above.**

However, when I try to use this method in the following manner, I'm getting an error saying that the types don't match:

```
doAnotherThing(new FooImpl());
```

`FooImpl` implements `Foo<T>`, so I don't see how this is an error?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?  Thanks

Comment: In your example, BarImpl does not extend Bar.

Comment: it works for me. Apart from the fact that you forgot `BarImpl extends Bar`

Comment: could you share the compiler error message?

Comment: The method doAnotherThing(Foo<T>) in the type *** is not applicable for the arguments (FooImpl)

Comment: Perhaps a better explanation of the file structure and location of the method doAnotherThing would help, because I was able to replicate without any trouble.

Bar.java:
abstract class Bar{
  public Bar(){
    doAnotherThing(new FooImpl());
  }

  <T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(Foo<T> foo){
    return foo.doSomething();
  }

  static class BarImpl extends Bar{}

  interface Foo<T extends Bar>{
    T doSomething();
  }

  static class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl>{
    public BarImpl doSomething(){
      return null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: EDIT: I added some more info to the question, as I was missing a major detail which seems to be causing the error.  Thanks

Comment: This is why you should not use artificial code samples to highlight your problem, unless you've actually run that code to confirm it still contains that problem and not others. Take a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Michael... I disagree.  It is often times not possible to post actual code on something like stack overflow due to licensing, NDAs, etc.  Also, most serious code bases are rather large, so an artificial code sample is the only feasible way without  pulling in other parts.  That said, I should've double checked that the artificial sample I created did indeed duplicate the problem.

Comment: @Polaris878: that's what I means with the second part of the sentence. Take a look at the link, it describes exactly what makes an ideal code sample

Comment: @Michael, Thanks... I'll make sure to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer changed to reflect clarification in question**

The complilation error (type mismatch) is actually perfectly correct. Note that the method definition says the parameter is a `List<Foo<T>>`. This means that the list can contain *any* `Foo<T>`, and the method must even be able to *add* any object that implements `Foo<T>`. And that's not the case when you give it a `List<FooImpl>`, because that is only allowed to contain instances of `FooImpl`. This works:

```
doAnotherThing(new ArrayList<Foo<BarImpl>>());
```

Mixing generics and polymorphism quickly leads to very complex scenarios, so it should be done sparingly.

Comment: Michael, this should be fixed.  Please see question again.  Thanks.

Comment: @Polaris878: changed answer, I think I have it now.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. I suspect whatever's causing the error, it isn't in the version you've got up above. Does the code below (all one file, `FooBarBaz.java`) compile for you? The only change I had to make to your code was to make `FooImpl.doSomething()` public. (Oh, and make it return something. `:)`)

```
public class FooBarBaz {

    <T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(Foo<T> foo) {
        return foo.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FooBarBaz().doAnotherThing(new FooImpl());
    }
}

abstract class Bar {
    // some neat stuff
}

class BarImpl extends Bar {
    // some cool stuff
}

interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T doSomething();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl> {
    public BarImpl doSomething() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Works fine for me with IDEA 9, JDK 1.6 on Mac OS 10.6.5.

Comment: You are correct, this does indeed work.  However I missed a (major) detail which I highlighted above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume `BarImpl extends Bar`, which I believe you meant from the beginning.

How does the augmented `Foo` interface look like?

Is it:

```
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T doSomething();
    T doAnotherThing(Foo<T> foo);
}
```

?

In such a case everything works with the following impl:

```
 class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl> {

 public BarImpl doSomething() {
  return null;
 }

 public BarImpl doAnotherThing(Foo<BarImpl> foo) {
  return null;
 }

}
```

---

Now, there might be a problem if you defined it otherwise:

```
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T doSomething();
    <T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(Foo<T> foo);
}
```

Because such a way of defining `doAnotherThing` introduces another generics parameter. What's confusing the interface's parameter and one from method share the name, i.e. `T`.
(BTW, I was surprised to learn Java allows such confusing name clash)

The last definition could be replaced with:

```
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T doSomething();
    <Y extends Bar> Y doAnotherThing(Foo<Y> foo);
}
```

which makes it more clear why `public BarImpl doAnotherThing(Foo<BarImpl> foo)` is not a proper way of overriding of this method.

Comment: `doAnotherThing` is not part of `Foo<T>`, it is part of another class

Comment: I see. My answer was a blind guess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my original answer is incorrect.  The following seems to work fine though.  Just make the doSomething method public and it compiles fine under Java6.

```
abstract class Bar {
    // some neat stuff
}

class BarImpl extends Bar {
    // some cool stuff
}

interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    public T doSomething();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl> {
    public BarImpl doSomething() {
        return null;
    }
}


public class Test {
<T extends Bar> T doAnotherThing(Foo<T> foo) {
    return foo.doSomething();
}

}
```